# Rails foreign_key not id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have two tables

```
class Sku < ApplicationRecord
  validates :sku, :supplier_code, :name, :price, presence: true
  belongs_to :supplier, class_name: 'Supplier', foreign_key: 'code'
end
```

and

```
 class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  validates :code, :name, presence: true
  has_many :skies, class_name: 'Sku'
end
```

i set `foreign_key` as a `code` field

but when i tried to create `sku` with `supplier_code` which i set to supplier

```
Supplier.create(code:4,name:2) => OK
```

i have got an error `{:supplier=>[{:error=>:blank}]},`

```
Sku.create(name:2,price:2,sku:3,supplier_code:4).errors
```

Comment: Try `belongs_to :supplier, primary_key: 'code', foreign_key: 'supplier_code'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must need to define on another model

```
class Sku < ApplicationRecord
  validates :sku, :supplier_code, :name, :price, presence: true
  belongs_to :supplier, class_name: 'Supplier', foreign_key: 'code'
end
```

and

```
class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  validates :code, :name, presence: true
  has_many :skies, class_name: 'Sku', primary_key: 'id', foreign_key: 'code'
end
```

Comment: why when i want to build Supplier.last.skies.new  is set supplier_code as supplier id but not like a supplier code?

Comment: `class_name: 'Supplier'` is redundant in `belongs_to` association.

Comment: Do we need to specify `primary_key: 'id'` in `has_many :skies`? Isn't that default value of it?